# Canvas fillRect() stops working after two iterations

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I saw an interesting creative maths plotting script using the modulo of the result of powers and wanted to experiment with it, changing the modulo iteratively.

Here we're drawing a 256x256 pattern and then after an interval changing the modulo value and redrawing (for simplicity just toggling the modulo between two values in an attempt to debug the problem).

It only draws two iterations before apparently the Canvas stops updating and we get stuck on the second pattern. I thought `context.clearRect()` might solve it but it makes no difference. The function keeps running because I get the `console.debug()` output but nothing updates visually.

I have the same result in both Chrome and Safari

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsbin.com/zacoperuho/edit?html,console,output

```
<canvas id="container"></canvas>
<script>
  container.width = 1024;
  container.height = 1024;
  const context = container.getContext("2d");
  var modulo = 9;
  
  function draw(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height);
    console.debug("modulo " + modulo)
    for (let x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < 256; y++) {      
        if ((x ^ y) % modulo) {
          context.fillRect(x*4, y*4, 4, 4);
        }
      }
    }
    if(modulo == 9){
      modulo = 7;
    } else {
      modulo = 9;
    }      
    
  }
  
  draw();
  setInterval(draw, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: This was incorrectly flagged as [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249234/get-canvas-width-and-height-using-javascript). Neither of the answers to the linked question mention `clearRect()` at all. Incorrect use of `clearRect()` was the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you need to clear the canvas's context and `context.clearRect` is the regular way to do it.

The problem are the parameters you're feeding it: `context.width, context.height`
The constant`context` is set to `getContext("2d")` thus it's an instance of
**CanvasRenderingContext2D**. This interface doesn't offer any properties called width or height. Instead you need to query the width & height on the Canvas element itself.

So simply change

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height);
```

to

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, container.width, container.height);
```

Comment: This works and solves the problem. What's curious is how my example successfully clears and draws the canvas a second time with `clearRect()` being used with undefined parameters or even with `clearRect()` being removed entirely.